# GUI to control sound

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

Is there any good GUI app to control my sound settings?

When I use Ubuntu, I use the sound indicator and have no problems with sound configuration. Unfortunately, sometimes sound stops working when I use an Ubuntu based distribution (for example, Lubuntu and Bodhi).

I searched in Google and read about Pulseaudio. Unfortunately, I did not manage to install it correctly. This is not an easy topic for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use `alsamixer` in the terminal if the GUI is broken. It's pretty easy to use; just use left/right key to move to different channels, and up/down key to adjust the levels. Then Esc to quit when you're done.

Comment: Have you tried gnome-alsamixer a gui utility to control alsa-mixer

Comment: @guruprasad: Thanks for your comment. I think Lubuntu does not have alsamixer but it can be installed anyways.

Comment: no gnome-alsamixer for me -- at least that I see so far.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pavucontrol && pavucontrol
```

Reboot. Change options in "Configuration" tab and you will suddenly hear the sound again.

Comment: This is a lifesaver. All of a sudden my audio in Chrome wouldn't adhere to the Ubuntu system sounds, but other programs like Zoom worked fine.