# After Installing Ubuntu 16.04 Two days ago I have no sound at all (youtube,loadspeaker or headphones)

Tags: alsa

After download and installation I have no sound at all anywhere (headphoneś loudspeakers ) The system seems to be working other than that. Can anyone tell me how to access the sound settings so that I can check them out? Thankś for any advice you can give. Am using my tower PC that was working OK with Ubuntu 14.04 before the new instalation.
I have tryed all the advice given but still no sound.It seems that alsa is not working as it should. Would a new instalation help  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching `pavucontrol` and check which devices are available and being used for output.  It may be that you've accidentally muted your primary output, or that the applications are outputting sound to the wrong channels.

Comment: Thankś , how do I launch ?   Daft question I know!.

Comment: Run `pavucontrol` from the launcher or the terminal.  If it's not there, use `apt-get install pavucontrol`.

Comment: Downloaded and installed.  Did a checkout and things seem to be OK but still will not work. No Sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my new Ubuntu 14.04 long ago.

My sound was actually muted and i installed ALSA and unmuted the sounds. There was a nice GUI, but i couldn't find about it now quickly.

This answer will help you to install the command line version and you can try to unmute the sounds.

[GUI to control sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389810/gui-to-control-sound)